# Get name of generic class without tilde

Tags: c#, generics, fully-qualified-naming

I am trying to get the type name of `T` using this:

```
typeof(T).Name
```

The name of the class is `ConfigSettings`

Instead of returning `ConfigSettings` it is returning `` ConfigSettings`1 ``.

Is there any specific reason why? How can I return the actual name without `` `1 ``?

Comment: "The name of the class is `ConfigSettings`" - no it isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The back-tick is indicative that the class is a generic type.  Probably the easiest thing is to just lop off anything from the back-tick forward:

```
string typeName = typeof(T).Name;
if (typeName.Contains('`')) typeName = typeName.Substring(0, typeName.IndexOf("`"));
```

Comment: Just be careful with nested types!

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier: typeof(T).Name.Split('`')[0];?

Comment: user2483744, yes that also works and is a bit more terse, but perhaps ever so slightly less clear what it's trying to do.  :)  +1 for you.

Comment: `LastIndexOf` would be safer with nested classes.

Answer (score 17):

Here is an extension method that will get the "real" name of a generic type along with the names of the generic type parameters.  It will properly handle nested generic types.

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetRealTypeName(this Type t)
    {
        if (!t.IsGenericType)
            return t.Name;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.IndexOf('`')));
        sb.Append('<');
        bool appendComma = false;
        foreach (Type arg in t.GetGenericArguments())
        {
            if (appendComma) sb.Append(',');
            sb.Append(GetRealTypeName(arg));
            appendComma = true;
        }
        sb.Append('>');
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is a sample program showing its usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).GetRealTypeName());
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<string>).GetRealTypeName());
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(long?).GetRealTypeName());
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Dictionary<int, List<string>>).GetRealTypeName());
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Func<List<Dictionary<string, object>>, bool>).GetRealTypeName());
}
```

And here is the output of the above program:

```
Int32
List<String>
Nullable<Int64>
Dictionary<Int32,List<String>>
Func<List<Dictionary<String,Object>>,Boolean>
```

Comment: That's actually really nice... I've added it to my library.  Not sure when I'll ever actually use it, but it feels good just having it there.  ;)

Comment: I don't if it is worth it performance wise, but I replaced your `foreach` loop with `sb.Append(string.Join(", ", t.GetGenericArguments().Select(type => type.GetRealTypeName())));`

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any specific reason why?

It means that the type has one generic type argument.

> How can I return the actual name without "`1"?

You can just find the index of ` (if it exists) and return the substring of the type name up to that character.