# Is there any way Csharp scripting API could infer types of arguments without having to specify it?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, csharpscript

I have the following piece of code:

```
string actionString = "(p1,p2)=>p1.HP-=20";

var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(SimplePlayer).Assembly).AddImports("Player");

var script = CSharpScript.Create<Action<SimplePlayer, SimplePlayer>>(actionString, options);

SimpleDeck d = new SimpleDeck(Game.GameController.Cards, 100, 100);

SimplePlayer p1 = new SimplePlayer(4000, 100, 100, d);
SimplePlayer p2 = new SimplePlayer(4000, 100, 100, d);

var del = script.CreateDelegate();

del.DynamicInvoke(p1, p2);
System.Console.WriteLine(p1.HP);
```

I want to achieve the same thing, but instead of having to specify the type of the expected delegate
I want something like this:

```
string actionString = "(p1,p2)=>p1.HP-=20";

var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(SimplePlayer).Assembly).AddImports("Player");

var script = CSharpScript.Create(actionString, options);

SimpleDeck d = new SimpleDeck(Game.GameController.Cards, 100, 100);

SimplePlayer p1 = new SimplePlayer(4000, 100, 100, d);
SimplePlayer p2 = new SimplePlayer(4000, 100, 100, d);

var del = script.CreateDelegate();

del.DynamicInvoke(p1, p2);
```

That throws me:

> error CS8917: The delegate type could not be inferred.

because i don't specify the type I want to be created. If I change the code to:

```
string actionString = "(SimplePlayer p1,SimplePlayer p2)=>p1.HP-=20";
```

Is there a way that I can infer the SimplePlayer type without having to explicitly pass it as an argument? And not having to do the following:

```
var script = CSharpScript.Create<Action<SimplePlayer, SimplePlayer>>(actionString, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need delegates to be resolved at runtime (in other words, without generics), one clusmy but working way would be to procedurally interpolate into the respective `Action` type around the expression before passing it onto `CSharpScript`. e.g.

```cs
string code = Typed(
    "(p1, p2) => p1.HP - 20",
    nameof(SimplePlayer), // first arg type name
    nameof(SimplePlayer) // second arg type name
);
// ((Action<SimplePlayer, SimplePlayer>)((p1, p2) => p1.HP - 20))

static string Typed(string code, params string[] args)
    => $"((Action<{string.Concat(", ", args)}>)({code}))";
```

If the return value may or may not exist, you can just as easily swap out the string.

Edit: To use whatever delegate type you wish, and not be constrained to `Action`'s overloads, you can just use [`Type.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.name?view=netstandard-1.6) as the interpolation. **Be aware that types with generics will not work in the example below**. To do that, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17481450/18052726).

```cs
static string Typed(string code, Type type)
    => $"(({type.Name})({code}))";
```

Though preferably, if you have the option to use generics, you can just do something like this.

```cs
Run<TDelegate>(string actionString, ScriptOptions options)
    where T : Delegate
{
    var del = CSharpScript.Create<TDelegate>(actionString, options);

    // del is now guaranteed to be 'Delegate' and you can treat it as such, and you can use typeof(T) to do whatever reflection APIs you require
}
```

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted something more elegant. I guess that's the only way that doesn't make things too complex. Thanks

Comment: Well actually that doesn't work because the workaround should be to interpolate the Type I want to infer

Comment: @RafaelAcosta I forgot that edits don't notify people; I have edited this post to reflect the things you mentioned.

Comment: Emik  that helps a lot,thanks